Flutter Build failed with an exception after update
Can you please help me what to do: my app built great,  until I updated flutter. Now I've got this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_mailer:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:C:\Users\zinch\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\008d07c96b1472e89d5ddc7f299cab36\transformed\core-1.13.1\res\values\values.xml:113:5-122:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

I don't use flutter_mailer in my project.
Flutter clean and invalidate cache didn't help.
Output of flutter doctor:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4780], locale ru-RU)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources


Try the workaround posted here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/153281#issuecomment-2292201697

@EdmundTam - great thanks to you!!! ) ... you save my life!

As Edmund Tam  wrote in comment, the solution is written here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/153281#issuecomment-2292201697.
replacing your subprojects block in your <project_root>/android/build.gradle with something along the lines of:
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.extensions.findByName("android") != null) {
            Integer pluginCompileSdk = project.android.compileSdk
            if (pluginCompileSdk != null && pluginCompileSdk < 31) {
                project.logger.error(
                        "Warning: Overriding compileSdk version in Flutter plugin: "
                                + project.name
                                + " from "
                                + pluginCompileSdk
                                + " to 31 (to work around https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199180389)."
                                + "\nIf there is not a new version of " + project.name + ", consider filing an issue against "
                                + project.name
                                + " to increase their compileSdk to the latest (otherwise try updating to the latest version)."
                )
                project.android {
                    compileSdk 31
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

Second subprojects block is required, or you've got an error while building.

Try this in your terminal and in the project directory
flutter clean

flutter pub get


Still the same error

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

try using "flutter clean" then "flutter pub get" this will resolve the issue.

Still the same error
